# how does PBS(polarized beam splitter) work?

Tags: optics

I know that beam splitter work with evanescent wave, and by adjusting the thickness between the two prism you can control the R,T to be 50%,50%.
But how does polarized beam splitters work?

Answer (score 1):

There are several different types of polarizing beam splitters. For example, if we have incident unpolarized light, a stack of plates tilted at the brewster angle would do the trick. The main pillar of this theory is that s-polarized and p-polarized light have different reflectivities for different incident angles.The Brewster angle is an angle at which incoming unpolarized light reflects s-polarized light and transmits the rest. By using a number of these plates, the incoming ray is sequentially depleted of s-polarized light and p-polarized light should be what comes out the other end and in the reflected direction we'd have nothing but s-polarized light.

EDIT: thought i'd clarify that this is ONE method of performing polarized beam splitting.